# Is this code simplified? Should I use more functions?

Tags: python, python-3.4

So I'm working on this program that opens an external file and then runs through it to see if it contains specific information. Is there a way to simplify it or is the way it is now the most efficient way write this?

```
def printGender(alist):
    if "Female" in alist:
        print(alist)
        print("Female Students")

def maleInfo(blist):
    if "2010" in blist:
        print(blist)
        print("Students who enrolled in 2010")

def csc2010(clist):
   if "CSC" in clist and "2010" in clist and "Female" in clist:
        print(clist)
        print("Female students who registered in CSC in 2010")

def main():
    ref = open("file1.txt","r")

    studentList = ref.readlines()
    ask = 10
    while ask != 0:
    print("1) print all female info")
    print("2) display all male info from 2010")
    print("3) display female students who registered for CSC in 2010")
    ask = int(input("Enter option 1, 2, 3 or 0 to quit: "))
    if ask == 1:
        for i in range(len(studentList)):
            alist = studentList[i]
            printGender(alist)
    elif ask == 2:
        for i in range(len(studentList)):
            blist = studentList[i]
            maleInfo(blist)
    elif ask == 3:
        for i in range(len(studentList)):
            clist = studentList[i]
            csc2010(clist)
    elif ask == 0:
        print("You chose to quit")
        break
    else:
        print("Not a Valid input")
        continue

    ref.close()

main()
```

Is there a way to simplify this code so that I don't create three seperate list in the main function.

```
    if ask == 1:
        for i in range(len(studentList)):
            alist = studentList[i]
            printGender(alist)
    elif ask == 2:
        for i in range(len(studentList)):
            blist = studentList[i]
            maleInfo(blist)
    elif ask == 3:
        for i in range(len(studentList)):
            clist = studentList[i]
            csc2010(clist)
    elif ask == 0:
        print("You chose to quit")
        break
    else:
    ect...
```

I was curious to see if there was a shorter way to get the same result. Maybe using a function that runns that section of code but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: This should be on code review.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It belongs on [codereview.se]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some problems to be aware of:

- the construct

  ```
  for i in range(len(studentList)):
      alist = studentList[i]
      printGender(alist)
  ```

  is pretty nasty; if you actually need `i` you should use

  ```
  for i, student in enumerate(student_list):
      print_gender(student)
  ```

  otherwise

  ```
  for student in student_list:
      print_gender(student)
  ```
- Your functions are poorly named; they don't do what they say they do! `printGender` prints female students, `printMale` prints students from 2010, etc. Similarly, your variable names are poorly chosen; `alist` is *not* a list of students, it is a single student.
- You seem to have a text string per student, at a guess something like `2009, 176915, Jones, Susan, Female, CSC`; but you make no attempt to separate out fields. This will lead to annoying problems with students like `2009, 292010, Male, Jill, Female, RCSCA` who will be reported as a student in both 2009 and 2010 (false match on student number), and both female and male (false match on last name), and in CSC (false match on course name). You really need to use a better data format - whether .csv or .json or a database, anything which returns named fields - to solve this problem.
- Your search options are non-orthogonal and limited to pre-coded options; you have no way of searching, for example, for all CSC students in 2007 without rewriting your program.

Fixing these problems leads you to something like

```
import json

def record_print_format(record):
    return "{Year:4} {Id:6} {Gender:6} {Firstname:>20} {Lastname:<20} {Course:6}".format(**record)

def show_records(records, format_fn=record_print_format):
    for r in records:
        print(format_fn(r))
    num = len(records)
    print("{} records:".format(num))

def filter_records(records, field, value):
    return [r for r in records if r[field] == value]

def match_year(records, year):
    return filter_records(records, "Year", year)

def match_gender(records, gender):
    return filter_records(records, "Gender", gender)

def match_course(records, course):
    return filter_records(records, "Course", course)

def main():
    with open("student_list.json") as studentfile:
        all_students = json.load(studentfile)
        records = all_students

    while True:
        print("1: Filter by year")
        print("2: Filter by gender")
        print("3: Filter by course")
        print("8: Show results")
        print("9: Clear filters")
        print("0: Exit")

        option = input("Please pick an option: ").strip()

        if option == "1":
            year = input("Which year? ").strip()
            records = match_year(records, year)
        elif option == "2":
            gender = input("Which gender? [Male|Female] ").strip()
            records = match_gender(records, gender)
        elif option == "3":
            course = input("Which course? ").strip()
            records = match_course(records, course)
        elif option == "8":
            show_records(records)
        elif option == "9":
            records = all_students
        elif option == "0":
            print("Goodbye!")
            break
        else:
            print("I don't recognize that option.")

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```